# Novel about a temporal erasure device

Tags: story-identification, novel

There is a book I was interested in but didn't buy. I remember the cover best, it had a man with a device with three antennas zapping a city block across the street causing it to vanish from reality. The device was described as being able to erase from existence anything it zapped. A similar device was used in The Year of Hell episodes from Star Trek Voyager and the De-Mat gun from Dr. Who.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192415/war-terrorism-where-pocket-calculator-deletes-reality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [War/Terrorism where Pocket Calculator Deletes Reality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192415/war-terrorism-where-pocket-calculator-deletes-reality)

Comment: Not eligible (at the moment) to be closed as a dupe as there is no confirmation that the OP is looking for the same story.

Answer (score 11):

That would be *War of Omission* by Kevin O'Donnell, Jr., published in 1982.  See [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553202812).

[image: War of Omission front cover]

Comment: That's an Amazon link, not a Wikipedia link...

Comment: Oops.  I've corrected the text. Thanks!