# Story about war fought using time manipulation

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm trying to identify a story about a conflict fought using time manipulation.

- One detail I think I remember correctly is about trapping some kind of
  a leader or general in a sphere altering time flow, said general
  would die due to some kind of sickness (cancer?).
- I believe there was also an undercover agent/spy meeting someone at a
  ball or party.
- There might have been something similar to MAD strategy, where time altering devices were placed along the border, ready to be activated on the first sight of enemies approaching, although I'm not sure about this part.
- I'm pretty sure I've heard this story in audio-book format in Polish, maybe a year or two years ago.

Comment: You have a nice description here but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know when you read/listened to this?

Comment: Possibly Kevin O'Donnell, Jr.'s *War of Omission*? https://www.fantasticfiction.com/o/kevin-odonnell-jr/war-of-omission.htm'

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen it seems that there are no audiobooks in Polish by this author

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - unlikely; that was the subject of [a question I asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192415/war-terrorism-where-pocket-calculator-deletes-reality); the plot and mechanism don't even come close to matching the querent's details here.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - I'd actually have been more inclined to think of [Vernor Vinge's _The Peace War_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Peace_War) or its sequelae, but what I remember of them doesn't quite match, either.

Comment: "Sphere" matches a bobble (Vinge), but basically all a bobble does is freeze its contents for a period of time.  (The larger the bobble, the longer the time; really big ones, like the Peacer bobble in _Marooned in Realtime_, lasted millions of years.)

Comment: This isn't *War of Omission*, that involved reality alteration, not time travel. Similarly Vinge's *Peace War* (and sequels) has no way to go back in time. The "meeting at a party" reminds me of several scenes in Fritz Leiber's "Change war" series, but if so lots of specifics have been forgotten. There have bene a lot of time travel/conflict stories over the years